# Last element index of an array with larger size

Tags: java, arrays

```
char[] someArray = new char[10];
someArray[0] ='a';
someArray[0] ='b';
someArray[0] ='c';
```

I want to add 'd' at the 4th position. How to get to the index which is one greater than the last valid element index in the array? `someArray.length-1` is returning 9. I want to get 4th position?

**EDIT:**
The code should be:

```
char[] someArray = new char[10];
someArray[0] ='a';
someArray[1] ='b';
someArray[2] ='c';
```

In this case I am aware of the fact that 4th index is free. If I have:

```
void abc(int[] x){
     //I want to add element in the next free index of the array x.
}
```

Comment: All character array elements are valid, even if you did not initialize them explicitly. You must remember (say, by storing in a variable) how many elements have been initialized. By the way, you initialized only the first element - but three times.

Comment: did you try someArray[3]? Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989200/6544931)

Comment: @Siddhart Shankar, You want to get the immediate free index of an array? meaning the next empty space after the last occupied one?

Comment: @Whales Yes. I want the immediate free index.

Comment: @Akash Mahapatra Updated the question.

Comment: @DYZ Please see my edited question

Comment: Once again, there is no such thing as a _free index_. You must keep track of the "unused" positions yourself by keeping a variable whose value is the length of the used portion.

Comment: No, it's not *adding* values to the array. It's *setting* the values of array elements. The array has the same size all the time. If you don't want that behaviour, use something like an `ArrayList`. Or if you want a value of U+0000 (`'\0'`) to mean "unused" then you can find the first index with that value. But you're not really "adding to" or "removing from" the array.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing in arrays starts from 0.

When you do `someArray.length-1`, it takes the length as it was initialized using 
`char[] someArray = new char[10];`

If you wish to reach the 4th location in your array, start counting from the 0th index and you would find that you need to use index 3 in your array and hence you might want to use 
`someArray[3] = desired_value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method to find out the index number of the first empty location in an array :

```
public static int getFirstEmptyIndex(char[] arr){
    int index=0;
    for(char a:arr){
      if(a==0)
      break;
      else
        index++;
    }
    return index;
  }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] someArray = new char[10];
    someArray[0]='a';
    someArray[1]='b';
    someArray[2]='c';
    someArray[getFirstEmptyIndex(someArray)]='d';    
    System.out.println(someArray[3]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! @Mohsen R. Aqdam

Answer (score 0):

First of all, but doing `someArray[0] = ..` you set the char in the first position of the array, and you override this value in this position in your code.

Secondly, the answer to your question is by doing `someArray[3] = 'd'`.
All elements in your array are valid, as long you are not reaching an index which is beyond your array size.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I think you need, it's similar to @Mohsen answer, just I think this will be more readable and straight forward.

```
private int nextFree(char[] arr){
        int i = 0;
        for(Character x : arr){
            if(x == 0)
                return i;
            i++;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

So you will get -1 if no free space rather than getting 0 and accidentally replacing index 0 value.

> > **Bonus::**
> >     if you which to get all the free space as an array in Ascending order, look below:

```
private int[] allFree(char[] ar){
        int s = 0;
        for(char c : ar){
            if(c==0)
                s++;
        }

        int[] k= new int[s];
        s=0;
        int ss=s;

        for(char c : ar){
            if(c==0){
                k[ss] = s;
                ss++;
            }
            s++;
        }

        return k;
    }
```

By the way, this is not the best algorithm for such operations, let anyone feel free to improve this.